# Plane equation question!

Tags: analytic-geometry

Could anyone explain me how to do tasks like this one:

Plane is intersecting Oy axis when $y = 3$ and line equation is $ 2x + 4=  y-2=z$      belonds to plane.

Write plane equation.

Comment: I edited your question. Check if it's correct or not? ($2x+4+y−2=z$)

Comment: Thanks for the correction,maybe you could help me with the problem now ? :)

Comment: Is that your homework or what? Have you learn it yet?

Comment: @Zia I think that    you are wrong.It is  the symmetric equations of the line.

Comment: It's not a homework, more then practise I need to understand in my course work. I have been given a canonical line form. Not sure how to use it to find plane as I described above.

Comment: @nadia-liza Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find  3 points which belong to plane. The first is $(0,3,0)$. if a  line  belongs to plane then all its points  belong to plane. Since points $(-2,2,0)$ and $(2,10,8)$ belong to the line $ 2x + 4=  y-2=z$ . We have the 3 points which belong to the plane. Formula on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry) (Defining a plane through three points) helps you write plane equation.

I am sorry for my English